# How to use & or and operation to get correct data when I am getting 'nan' for all values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to manipulate some data but as I am not really firm with Python, I am here to ask this question.

```
test_val_set = merged_data2.loc[merged_data2.reject_yn=='Y'] & 
merged_data2.loc[merged_data2.reject_yn=='N'].iloc[70000:,:]
```

Like above, I am trying to get this two conditions to be combined for my final
desired information. But When I do, it gives me correct raw x column but 
data point values are all 'nan'.

When I use them separately as below,

```
a = merged_data2.loc[merged_data2.reject_yn=='Y']
b = merged_data2.loc[merged_data2.reject_yn=='N'].iloc[70000:,:]
```

they all work just fine with correct values in it.

How can I use this '&'? or is there any other way around?

Thank you people in advance.

Comment: If the question is related to numpy, scipy or similar you should add an appropriate tag.

Comment: The value can not be equal to both Y and N , you need to clarify your problem

Answer (score 0):

Base on you description , you can `concat` the two dataframe back

```
a = merged_data2.loc[merged_data2.reject_yn=='Y']
b = merged_data2.loc[merged_data2.reject_yn=='N'].iloc[70000:,:]

df=pd.concat([a,b])
```